# Aligning multiple <p> tags as text

Tags: html, css

How can i aligning texts in multiple html p tags:

```
<div>
<p>aaaaaa</p>
<p>bbbbbbbbbbb</p>
<p>cccccccccccc</p>
</div>
```

Making them have word-wrap property like normal text and break line like below?

```
aaaaaa bbbbbbb
bbbb ccccccccc
ccc
```

Text in p tags needs to be dynamic and trigger seperate events onClick. Is there any css tricks like
"display: flex" that can achieve this?

---

edit:

Sorry for being unclear, I would try to explain again.

I would like to put the 3 p tags into a container that have uninsuffiecnt width to display all in one line.
And the desired beviour would be something like this: [desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rsz2p.png)

```html
<style>
    div {
        display: flex;
        max-width: 200px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        line-break: anywhere;
    }
</style>
<div>
    <p onclick="someEvent()">aaaaaaa</p>
    <p onclick="someEvent()">bbbbb</p>
    <p onclick="someEvent()">ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc</p>
</div>
```

Above Snippet is my failed attempt, hope this helps in explaining my question

Comment: What information do the `<p>` elements contain? Because a `<p>` element is a semantic grouping of content that represents a specific portion of related content, or thoughts. Would a list be more correct for this content?

Comment: I'm not downvoting this question, but it sounds confusing. How many letters do you need in the first group/row? Any character limits, etc.

Comment: @SanthoshJohn Sorry for not being clear enough. I want the word in p tag could line break when it exceeds the max width.

Comment: Have you tried `p { display: inline; }` ?

Comment: @Yukititit: Okay. This is super simple if I got your question correctly. Adding it in the answer section in a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your desired output by using the following code:

**Run this snippet to show the output.**

```css
.container {
  max-width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: yellow;
}

p {
  word-break: break-all;
  white-space: normal;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <p class="word-break" onclick="someEvent()">aaaaaaa</p>
  <p class="word-break" onclick="someEvent()">bbbbb</p>
  <p class="word-break" onclick="someEvent()">ccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc</p>
</div>
```

Aside from that, here is a demo of my JS fiddle. : https://jsfiddle.net/rutikpatel/d1s7t64g/

---

Screenshot of output : 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend flexbox:

```html
<style>
    div {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        align-items: flex-start;
        justify-content: flex-start;
    }
</style>
<div>
    <p onclick="someEvent()">aaaaaa</p>
    <p onclick="someEvent()">bbbbbbbbbbb</p>
    <p onclick="someEvent()">cccccccccccc</p>
</div>
```

You can also use `text-align` to align the text in multiple `<p>` tags within the `<div/>`.

```html
<style>
    div {
        text-align: justify;
        white-space: pre-wrap;
    }
</style>
<div>
    <p onclick="someEvent()">aaaaaa</p>
    <p onclick="someEvent()">bbbbbbbbbbb</p>
    <p onclick="someEvent()">cccccccccccc</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I am sorry but none of above work for me, can you provide a snippet for example?

Answer (score 0):

Use the CSS' property `word-break: break-all` to achieve the desired result.

```css
.my-block {
  max-width: 75px;
  padding: 5px;
  word-break: break-all; 
}

.my-block--design {
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0 red;
}
```

```html
<p class="my-block my-block--design">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur officiis cupiditate placeat. Numquam, error dicta ea voluptatem cupiditate dolore, aperiam aspernatur at, quaerat est repellat possimus!
</p>
```

Please Note: Decrease the `max-width` manually for now, to see every letter-by-letter break. You can also use `relative` unit(s). For demo purposes, I've used an `absolute` unit. More here on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vL4tyhzx/17/)